# Moving to a new server. What happens to my POP3 email linked with Outlook?

Tags: email, webmail

I am moving my web server to another host in a few days and I have a concern about the emails. Currently, I am an Outlook user and instead of visiting the webmail's web server to read my emails, I connected it there. I use POP3 so emails are downloaded form server to my computer and stored locally.

When I move to a new host, having the same incoming / outgoing server ( mail.domain.com ) (I think this is standard on Cpanel) will I lose my old email from showing in Outlook?

I know I can't see them through the "old" host, but this is ok. I need to keep them locally and continue with the new host.

Is this what happens, or should I do anything to keep my old emails locally and continue with the new ones from the new server?

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate the website from old to new provider in cPanel format. It will be migrated as it is and will transfer the emails as well. Please check with your new host as to how they are going to perform the transfer.

On a safer side, download all the emails on your local machine using Outlook. Doing this, all emails from old host will be downloaded on your machine and you can start fresh with new host. To download all the emails on local machine using Outlook, Untick the option "Leave a Copy of Message on the server". This will download all the emails on your local machine.

Make sure to tick it again once you are done downloading all the emails.